# Biblatex: Per-entry changes to citation field

Tags: biblatex, citing

This should be a relatively quick question. I'm using Biblatex's authoryear(-icomp, not that that really matters here) citation style, but there are a small number of works where the author-year format makes no sense, and I'd rather have them show up as author-title. For example, I would like that for the following bibliography entry

```
@BOOK{JahizBayaan,
  title = {al-Bayān wa-al-tabyīn},
  author = {al-Jāḥiẓ, Abū ʻUthman ibn Baḥr},
  editor = {Hārūn, ʻAbd al-Salām Muḥammad},
  year = {1968},
  owner = {Alexander},
  timestamp = {2011.12.23}
}
```

the command

```
\citet{JahizBayaan}
```

produce

> Al-Jahiz (*Al-Bayaan wa-Tabyiin*)

rather than what I currently get, which is

> Al-Jahiz (1968)

I could obviously make a command specifically for this author, or for works of this type, but I would really like it if there was a way to do this per-entry in the bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: if you highlight code snippets and press the `{}` button, the code will appear as such.

Comment: You can redefine citet or you create a new cite command via DeclareCiteCommand.

Comment: Thanks egreg, I tried to do that but got confused by the interface here. Marco - I would like if it was more seamless, so that I could cite multiple keys, including this one, i.e.: \citet{Ferguson59,JahizBayaan,Chomsky64} and it would produce "Ferguson (1959); Jahiz (Al-Bayaan wa-t-tabyiin); Chomsky (1964)" without the need to redefine a command.

Comment: At the moment I can't test but you can try something like this: `\AtEveryCitekey{\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{JahizBayaan}{True}{FALSE}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{notyear}
\addtocategory{notyear}{A01}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcategory{notyear}{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\printfield{title}}%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{A01}

\textcite{B02}

\textcite{C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what's going on here. The .bib entries and the citations look identical as far as I can tell, so I don't understand what's causing the citation for "Author" to show up differently.

Comment: @Skander: The citekey for "Author" is `A01`, and it has been added to a category "notyear" for which the year in citations (`labelyear` plus `extrayear`) is replaced with the content of the `title` field.

Comment: Ok, this works. It would be nice if I could just include some property in the bibliography entry itself, but this is workable. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to try using \ifkeyword and putting a keyword into the bibliography, and that should give me the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: @Skander: I checked the manual, and `\ifkeyword` seems like a good idea indeed. Please don't forget to upvote my answer (this has to be done separately from accepting it).

Answer (score 4):

I altered this so that it is based on keywords in the bibliography, and thus will translate more easily between documents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifkeyword{notyear}{% Here I use \ifkeyword instead of \ifcategory
    \DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\printfield{title}}%
    \DeclareFieldFormat{extrayear}{}%
  }{%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {notyear}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{A01}

\textcite{B02}

\textcite{C03}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The output is identical.

Comment: If you are using Biber, you can also add such keywords automatically during parsing by matching the AUTHOR field, for example. This is useful if you can't or don't want to change the .bib. See section 3.1.1 of the Biber manual.